# On google billing account I have this error. This action couldn't be completed. Try again later. [OR_BACR2_34]

Tags: google-api, google-developers-console

I am trying to add google billing account to subscribe in google translate API. after I fill billing profile and enter my visa card info I got this error This action couldn't be completed. Try again later. [OR_BACR2_34]

I tried multiple cards, one of them is debit card for USA bank and I checked the country is the same country of card but it doesn't work. Moreover, every time I click on start free to subscribe it takes one dollar from my account and get it back which mean the card is working.